# Download from list of wget command saved in txt file

Tags: linux, wget, download

I have list of wget command as shown below:

```
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2009_12//00030352160/auxil/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2020_11//00031630169/xrt/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2017_03//00034228170/auxil/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2020_03//00031630125/log/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2008_11//00030352101/auxil/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2014_04//00035014140/log/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2017_03//00034228172/auxil/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2017_04//00034228177/auxil/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2014_04//00035014133/auxil/
wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2019_12//00031630093/auxil/
```

These are saved in a filename.txt. How to download? How can I see the progress of download also in log file?

Comment: To answer the first question, just run `sh filename.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution and a simple solution.

As berndbausch said, you could either just run `bash filename.txt` as shellscripts are basically texfiles with lists of commands, just as your textfile.

Or you could do something more clever, but maybe not that useful for this usecase:
If you got a list of links (https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2009_12//00030352160/auxil/, https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2020_11//00031630169/xrt/, ...) you can wirte them in you textfile, and the use that textfile as an input for wget.

textfile.txt:

```
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2009_12//00030352160/auxil/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2020_11//00031630169/xrt/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2017_03//00034228170/auxil/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2020_03//00031630125/log/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2008_11//00030352101/auxil/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2014_04//00035014140/log/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2017_03//00034228172/auxil/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2017_04//00034228177/auxil/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2014_04//00035014133/auxil/
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2019_12//00031630093/auxil
```

an then:
`wget -q -nH --no-check-certificate --cut-dirs=5  -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*'  -erobots=off --retr-symlinks -i textfile.txt`